# How to create custom widgets for Qt

Tags: qt, widget

I am trying my hands on Qt custom widget. I am working on this example http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/designer-customwidgetplugin.html

I have changed nothing as mentioned in the example. I am able to generate a `.so` file in the designer folder, but then nothing happens after that. I am not able to see the plugin in my Qt editor. When I check the `Tools-> Forms editor->About Qt Designer plugins`, I find just one plugin `QtWebView` which was a default plugin.

Where am I going wrong. Where do I find the Qt plugins?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Designer plugins go to the plugins/designer subdirectory of your Qt installation. Alternatively, you can set QT_PLUGIN_PATH. For example, add mybuilddir/plugins to QT_PLUGIN_PATH if your plugin is in mybuilddir/plugins/designer.

Comment: umm ... how to set QT_PLUGIN_PATH ?

Comment: For your application, you can set it in your Run Environment (Projects->Run Settings->Run Environment). For designer, you'll have to set it as environment variable for the session creator/designer runs in (e.g. a batch file, or your user's environment).